# Cassandra node running, but cant connect?

Tags: cassandra, garbage-collection, cassandra-3.0

using Cassandra version 3.11.8, openjdk-8u242-b08

Prior to this crashing, I was altering a table with 50k+ columns so this might (is) a factor to all of this. I would Ideally rather lose the data in the commit (if its inserting a backlog still perpetually) so I can connect to the hosts so service can be resumed.

Before start of error, I started alter table commands inserting many columns into the table in calls of 1000 at a time. Eventually after it may have done about half of them i received this error for all the nodes.

> 2020-09-10 15:34:29 WARNING  [control connection] Error connecting to
> 127.0.0.3:9042: Traceback (most recent call last):   File "cassandra\cluster.py", line 3522, in
> cassandra.cluster.ControlConnection._reconnect_internal   File
> "cassandra\cluster.py", line 3591, in
> cassandra.cluster.ControlConnection._try_connect   File
> "cassandra\cluster.py", line 3588, in
> cassandra.cluster.ControlConnection._try_connect   File
> "cassandra\cluster.py", line 3690, in
> cassandra.cluster.ControlConnection._refresh_schema   File
> "cassandra\metadata.py", line 142, in
> cassandra.metadata.Metadata.refresh   File "cassandra\metadata.py",
> line 165, in cassandra.metadata.Metadata._rebuild_all   File
> "cassandra\metadata.py", line 2522, in get_all_keyspaces   File
> "cassandra\metadata.py", line 2031, in get_all_keyspaces   File
> "cassandra\metadata.py", line 2719, in
> cassandra.metadata.SchemaParserV3._query_all   File
> "cassandra\connection.py", line 985, in
> cassandra.connection.Connection.wait_for_responses   File
> "cassandra\connection.py", line 983, in
> cassandra.connection.Connection.wait_for_responses   File
> "cassandra\connection.py", line 1435, in
> cassandra.connection.ResponseWaiter.deliver
> cassandra.OperationTimedOut: errors=None, last_host=None

I am running 8 nodes on a server. I have reset all nodes and handshakes are done. But I cannot make a connect to my cluster on any of the nodes.My system.log and debug.log have similar logs throughout once cassandra starts running. gc.log has not updated in some time so it makes me wonder what is going on? Interesting point is i only retrieve the list of columns in the table 3 times total, I have ran this code on my desktop without issues using 2 nodes (much much less resources) and have not received any of these issues.

Edit: just for clarity my application/connections are not running and these logs below are what is happening periodically..I tried looking at scheduled tasks and cannot find information about cassandra for this. I wonder what backlog its reading from and if I can stop it. Ideally I would like to stop this backload of operations from happening...

```
-------SYSTEM.LOG-------
INFO  [GossipStage:1] 2020-09-10 17:38:52,376 StorageService.java:2400 - Node /127.0.0.9 state jump to NORMAL
WARN  [OptionalTasks:1] 2020-09-10 17:38:54,802 CassandraRoleManager.java:377 - CassandraRoleManager skipped default role setup: some nodes were not ready
INFO  [OptionalTasks:1] 2020-09-10 17:38:54,802 CassandraRoleManager.java:416 - Setup task failed with error, rescheduling
INFO  [HANDSHAKE-/127.0.0.4] 2020-09-10 17:38:56,965 OutboundTcpConnection.java:561 - Handshaking version with /127.0.0.4
INFO  [HANDSHAKE-/127.0.0.4] 2020-09-10 17:38:58,262 OutboundTcpConnection.java:561 - Handshaking version with /127.0.0.4
INFO  [GossipStage:1] 2020-09-10 17:38:59,102 Gossiper.java:1139 - Node /127.0.0.4 has restarted, now UP
INFO  [GossipStage:1] 2020-09-10 17:38:59,103 TokenMetadata.java:497 - Updating topology for /127.0.0.4
INFO  [GossipStage:1] 2020-09-10 17:38:59,103 TokenMetadata.java:497 - Updating topology for /127.0.0.4
INFO  [GossipStage:1] 2020-09-10 17:38:59,105 Gossiper.java:1103 - InetAddress /127.0.0.4 is now UP
INFO  [HANDSHAKE-/127.0.0.5] 2020-09-10 17:38:59,813 OutboundTcpConnection.java:561 - Handshaking version with /127.0.0.5
INFO  [GossipStage:1] 2020-09-10 17:39:00,104 StorageService.java:2400 - Node /127.0.0.4 state jump to NORMAL
INFO  [HANDSHAKE-/127.0.0.5] 2020-09-10 17:39:01,029 OutboundTcpConnection.java:561 - Handshaking version with /127.0.0.5
INFO  [GossipStage:1] 2020-09-10 17:39:01,266 Gossiper.java:1139 - Node /127.0.0.5 has restarted, now UP
INFO  [GossipStage:1] 2020-09-10 17:39:01,267 TokenMetadata.java:497 - Updating topology for /127.0.0.5
INFO  [GossipStage:1] 2020-09-10 17:39:01,267 TokenMetadata.java:497 - Updating topology for /127.0.0.5
INFO  [GossipStage:1] 2020-09-10 17:39:01,270 Gossiper.java:1103 - InetAddress /127.0.0.5 is now UP
INFO  [GossipStage:1] 2020-09-10 17:39:04,271 StorageService.java:2400 - Node /127.0.0.5 state jump to NORMAL
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2020-09-10 17:43:05,805 NoSpamLogger.java:91 - Some operations were slow, details available at debug level (debug.log)
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2020-09-10 17:48:40,892 NoSpamLogger.java:91 - Some operations were slow, details available at debug level (debug.log)
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2020-09-10 17:54:35,999 NoSpamLogger.java:91 - Some operations were slow, details available at debug level (debug.log)
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2020-09-10 17:59:36,083 NoSpamLogger.java:91 - Some operations were slow, details available at debug level (debug.log)
INFO  [Service Thread] 2020-09-10 18:00:24,722 GCInspector.java:285 - ParNew GC in 237ms.  CMS Old Gen: 717168160 -> 887151520; Par Eden Space: 1718091776 -> 0; Par Survivor Space: 12757512 -> 214695936
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2020-09-10 18:04:56,160 NoSpamLogger.java:91 - Some operations were slow, details available at debug level (debug.log)

------DEBUG.LOG------
INFO  [Service Thread] 2020-09-10 18:00:24,722 GCInspector.java:285 - ParNew GC in 237ms.  CMS Old Gen: 717168160 -> 887151520; Par Eden Space: 1718091776 -> 0; Par Survivor Space: 12757512 -> 214695936
DEBUG [ScheduledTasks:1] 2020-09-10 18:00:26,102 MonitoringTask.java:173 - 1 operations were slow in the last 4996 msecs:
<SELECT * FROM system_schema.columns>, was slow 2 times: avg/min/max 1256/1232/1281 msec - slow timeout 500 msec
DEBUG [ScheduledTasks:1] 2020-09-10 18:00:56,110 MonitoringTask.java:173 - 1 operations were slow in the last 5007 msecs:
<SELECT * FROM system_schema.columns>, time 795 msec - slow timeout 500 msec
DEBUG [ScheduledTasks:1] 2020-09-10 18:01:01,111 MonitoringTask.java:173 - 1 operations were slow in the last 5003 msecs:
<SELECT * FROM system_schema.columns>, time 808 msec - slow timeout 500 msec
DEBUG [ScheduledTasks:1] 2020-09-10 18:03:41,143 MonitoringTask.java:173 - 1 operations were slow in the last 5002 msecs:
<SELECT * FROM system_schema.columns>, time 853 msec - slow timeout 500 msec
DEBUG [ScheduledTasks:1] 2020-09-10 18:04:06,148 MonitoringTask.java:173 - 1 operations were slow in the last 4996 msecs:
<SELECT * FROM system_schema.columns>, time 772 msec - slow timeout 500 msec
DEBUG [ScheduledTasks:1] 2020-09-10 18:04:26,153 MonitoringTask.java:173 - 1 operations were slow in the last 4991 msecs:
<SELECT * FROM system_schema.columns>, time 838 msec - slow timeout 500 msec
DEBUG [ScheduledTasks:1] 2020-09-10 18:04:31,154 MonitoringTask.java:173 - 1 operations were slow in the last 5009 msecs:
<SELECT * FROM system_schema.columns>, time 841 msec - slow timeout 500 msec
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2020-09-10 18:04:56,160 NoSpamLogger.java:91 - Some operations were slow, details available at debug level (debug.log)
DEBUG [ScheduledTasks:1] 2020-09-10 18:04:56,160 MonitoringTask.java:173 - 1 operations were slow in the last 5004 msecs:
<SELECT * FROM system_schema.columns>, time 772 msec - slow timeout 500 msec
DEBUG [ScheduledTasks:1] 2020-09-10 18:05:11,165 MonitoringTask.java:173 - 1 operations were slow in the last 4994 msecs:
<SELECT * FROM system_schema.columns>, time 808 msec - slow timeout 500 msec
DEBUG [ScheduledTasks:1] 2020-09-10 18:05:31,171 MonitoringTask.java:173 - 1 operations were slow in the last 5004 msecs:
<SELECT * FROM system_schema.columns>, time 834 msec - slow timeout 500 msec
DEBUG [ScheduledTasks:1] 2020-09-10 18:05:56,176 MonitoringTask.java:173 - 1 operations were slow in the last 5010 msecs:
<SELECT * FROM system_schema.columns>, was slow 2 times: avg/min/max 847/837/857 msec - slow timeout 500 msec
DEBUG [ScheduledTasks:1] 2020-09-10 18:07:16,196 MonitoringTask.java:173 - 1 operations were slow in the last 5003 msecs:
<SELECT * FROM system_schema.columns>, time 827 msec - slow timeout 500 msec
DEBUG [ScheduledTasks:1] 2020-09-10 18:07:31,200 MonitoringTask.java:173 - 1 operations were slow in the last 5007 msecs:
<SELECT * FROM system_schema.columns>, time 834 msec - slow timeout 500 msec
DEBUG [ScheduledTasks:1] 2020-09-10 18:08:01,207 MonitoringTask.java:173 - 1 operations were slow in the last 5000 msecs:
<SELECT * FROM system_schema.columns>, time 799 msec - slow timeout 500 msec
DEBUG [ScheduledTasks:1] 2020-09-10 18:08:16,211 MonitoringTask.java:173 - 1 operations were slow in the last 4999 msecs:
<SELECT * FROM system_schema.columns>, time 780 msec - slow timeout 500 msec
DEBUG [ScheduledTasks:1] 2020-09-10 18:08:36,217 MonitoringTask.java:173 - 1 operations were slow in the last 5000 msecs:
<SELECT * FROM system_schema.columns>, time 835 msec - slow timeout 500 msec
DEBUG [ScheduledTasks:1] 2020-09-10 18:09:01,221 MonitoringTask.java:173 - 1 operations were slow in the last 5002 msecs:
<SELECT * FROM system_schema.columns>, time 832 msec - slow timeout 500 msec
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2020-09-10 18:09:56,231 NoSpamLogger.java:91 - Some operations were slow, details available at debug level (debug.log)
DEBUG [ScheduledTasks:1] 2020-09-10 18:09:56,231 MonitoringTask.java:173 - 1 operations were slow in the last 4995 msecs:
<SELECT * FROM system_schema.columns>, time 778 msec - slow timeout 500 msec
DEBUG [ScheduledTasks:1] 2020-09-10 18:10:06,233 MonitoringTask.java:173 - 1 operations were slow in the last 5009 msecs:
<SELECT * FROM system_schema.columns>, time 1099 msec - slow timeout 500 msec
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The timeout is from the driver trying to parse the schema while establishing the control connection.

The driver uses the control connection for admin tasks such as discovering the cluster's topology and schema during the initialisation phase. I've discussed it in a bit more detail in this post -- https://community.datastax.com/questions/7702/.

In your case, the driver initialisation times out while parsing the thousands of columns in the table you mentioned. I have to admit that this is new to me. I've never worked with a cluster that had thousands of columns so I'm curious to know what your use case is and perhaps there might be a better data model for it.

As a workaround, you can try to bump out the default timeout to see if the driver is able to eventually initialise. However, this is going to be a band-aid solution since the driver needs to parse the schema every time a DDL takes place. Cheers!

Comment: Thats a good point. Making the timeout to none did remedy this issue. We originally had our columns 50k+ columns passed into a map column but the decoding (passing and flattening the map into a pandas dataframe) took significant time. If we can store it as wide columns I think we could remedy this. I looked that cassandra can store 2 billion columns so I thought it would be a better approach for our use case

Comment: Yes, theoretically but that's really about wide partitions, not so much table columns if that makes sense. :)